# How can I reorganise the package list in aptitude's graphical (TUI) mode?

Tags: apt

As shown here in the [debian aptitude reference guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch01s01s02.en.html), aptitude's default package list organisation is:

[image]

Here it is grouped by "installed/not installed", How can I customise this list to group packages by other criteria such as the "archive" (e.g. unstable) or outstanding actions or other such criteria?

Note: I know aptitude can do this, I just can't remember how to do it.

Comment: The concepts of a _textual user interface_ and a _graphical user interface_ are usually considered to be non-overlapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Options -> Preferences, there is a possibility to change the default grouping method. That sounds like what you're looking for.

More details can be found in the [Aptitude user's manual, section 2.5.1](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s05s01.en.html#secGroupingPolicy). It contains a large table of various grouping rules, so I don't reproduce it here.